# Algorithm to detect if a word in an array matches a given string + regex? RUBY

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I'm trying to build a simple algorithm to detect if a word in an array matches a given string (in this case, g) uniquely--as in, only 1 appearance of the characters in g, AND an unlimited amount of appearances of the vowels--aeiouy.

```
g = "bs"


arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']

for y in arr
  return y if y.include? { |z| /[aeiouy]/ =~ z } and y.include? { |z|/[ #{g} ]/ =~ z }

end
```

Expected output:

```
base
bees
# all others either have more than 1 b or s, or contain other consonants.
```

Getting this error:

```
include?': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I think there could be better ways of doing this, using .find or .any? perhaps?

Comment: the `include()` method does not take a block. It only takes a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample in the question, I presume two cases:

1. The order of consonants on `g = "bs"` should remain same in the target.
2. The order of consonants doesn't matter. So it `g = "bs"` will also match a the strings "sb", "sabe", "sob", "boose" etc.

For case 1:

You can first remove all vowels from target words in the `arr` array. Then match it with the pattern in `g`, and select only those words which match.

```
g = "bs"
arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']
arr.map{ |x| [x, x.gsub(/[aeiou]/,'')] }.select{ |x| x[1] == g }.map{|x| x[0]}
# ["base", "bees"]
```

For case2, simply sort the source string characters and target string characters before a match:

```
g = "bs"
arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']
v1 = arr.map{ |x| [x, x.gsub(/[aeiou]/,'')] }.select{ |x| x[1] == g }.map{|x| x[0]}
p v1 
# ["base", "bees"]

arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss', "sb", "sabe", "sob", "boose"]
v2 = arr.map{ |x| [x, x.gsub(/[aeiou]/,'')] }.select{ |x| x[1].split("").sort == g.split("").sort }.map{|x| x[0]}
p v2
# ["base", "bees", "sb", "sabe", "sob", "boose"]
```

Depending on the amount of data in `arr` you can keep the intermediate values pre-processed for faster results.

Comment: `== g` is insufficient, since it bakes in the order for the consonants. Your code would not match `"sub"`, and it should. You can fix by sorting characters of `x[1]` and `g` before comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#grep` method ([core lib](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)) and `String#count` ([codelib](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-count))

We look for words contained both characters (b and s) only once.

```
g = ["b", "s"]    
arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']

arr.grep(/[aeiouy]/).select { |w| g.all? { |s| w.count(s) == 1  } }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the characters should be taken into account:

```
g = "bs"
arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']
arr.select{|w| w.tr("aeiouy", "") == g}
```

If the order of the characters should not be taken into account:

```
g = "bs"
g = g.each_char.sort
arr = ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss']
arr.select{|w| w.tr("aeiouy", "").each_char.sort == g}
```

Comment: the original solution was adequate, you don't need to sort the chars I guess

Comment: @bjhaid Thanks. The question was not clear to me. I will post both just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
2.0.0p247 :122 > ['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss'].select do |x|  
  x.match /^(?>b)[^bs]*(?>s)[^bs]*\b/
end
=> ["base", "bees"]
```

## EDIT

Matching unlimited amount of vowels aeiouy

```
['base', 'vase', 'race', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss'].select do |x|
  x.match /^(?>b)[aeiouy]*(?>s)[aeiouy]*\b/
end
=> ["base", "bees"]
```

Comment: I suggest you break your statement into two lines so readers don't have to scroll horizontally to read your code.  Here you could make the first line `['base',...].` or add a line continuation character to split elsewhere, e.g., `['base',...].select { |x| \ `.